# How to add host/owner to an existing cluster service

Tags: cluster-computing

I have a cluster server and has added 1 generic service.

The service has owner as one of the cluster server. Now I am installing the same service on the other cluster host server and I want to add this new cluster server as available host to the same cluster generic service.

Is there any specific command to do so? I want to do so through coding using C#. I was able to do it manually by going to that service property and add owners. But i want to do the same using C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after googling and trial and error method, got working

This is the command we need to execute

```
Set-ClusterOwnerNode -Group <CLUSTERGROUPNAME> -Owners <OWNER1>,<OWNER2>
```

Don't forget to import Failover cluster module before executing the above command

```
Import-Module FailoverClusters
```